# need a spinner and dialog box in async API call function

Tags: flutter, dart, http

I have developed an image uploading API and called it an async function I need a spinner to make load until it fetches the result and after fetching the result it has to show the response received in an alert box

```
uploadImage() async {
    final request = http.MultipartRequest(
        "POST",
        Uri.parse(
            'https://f77f-2402-d000-a500-73e5-8c48-4e9a-dad0-c14f.in.ngrok.io/upload'));
    final headers = {"Content-type": "multipart/form-data"};
    request.files.add(http.MultipartFile("image",
        selectedImage!.readAsBytes().asStream(), selectedImage!.lengthSync(),
        filename: selectedImage!.path.split("/").last));
    request.fields['userId'] = 'value';
    request.headers.addAll(headers);
    final response = await request.send().then((value) => null);
    _isInAsyncCall = true;
    http.Response res = await http.Response.fromStream(response);
    final resJson = jsonDecode(res.body);
    message = resJson['message'];
    print(message);
    setState(() {
      
    });
```

My whole flutter code is here

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
 

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'find waste collector'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});
   

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  File? selectedImage;
  String? message;
bool _isInAsyncCall = false;

  uploadImage() async {
    final request = http.MultipartRequest(
        "POST",
        Uri.parse(
            'https://f77f-2402-d000-a500-73e5-8c48-4e9a-dad0-c14f.in.ngrok.io/upload'));
    final headers = {"Content-type": "multipart/form-data"};
    request.files.add(http.MultipartFile("image",
        selectedImage!.readAsBytes().asStream(), selectedImage!.lengthSync(),
        filename: selectedImage!.path.split("/").last));
    request.fields['userId'] = 'value';
    request.headers.addAll(headers);
    final response = await request.send().then((value) => null);
    _isInAsyncCall = true;
    http.Response res = await http.Response.fromStream(response);
    final resJson = jsonDecode(res.body);
    message = resJson['message'];
    print(message);
    setState(() {
      
    });
  }

  Future getImage() async {
    final pickedImage =
        await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    selectedImage = File(pickedImage!.path);
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also a layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            selectedImage == null
                ? Text("please pick a image to upload")
                : Image.file(selectedImage!),
        inAsyncCall: _isInAsyncCall,
        // demo of some additional parameters
        opacity: 0.5,
        progressIndicator: CircularProgressIndicator(),    
            TextButton.icon(
                style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                        Color.fromARGB(255, 62, 187, 0))),
                onPressed: uploadImage,
                icon: Icon(Icons.upload_file_rounded, color: Colors.black38),
                label: Text("Upload waste sample Image",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)))
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: getImage,
        child: Icon(Icons.add_a_photo),
      ),
      // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

modal_progress_hud library helped lot on making this task

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter_progress_hud/flutter_progress_hud.dart';
import 'package:modal_progress_hud_nsn/modal_progress_hud_nsn.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'find waste collector'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  File? selectedImage;
  String? message;
  bool showSpinner = false;

  uploadImage() async {
    setState(() {
      showSpinner = true;
    });
    final request = http.MultipartRequest(
        "POST",
        Uri.parse(
            'https://f77f-2402-d000-a500-73e5-8c48-4e9a-dad0-c14f.in.ngrok.io/upload'));
    final headers = {"Content-type": "multipart/form-data"};
    request.files.add(http.MultipartFile("image",
        selectedImage!.readAsBytes().asStream(), selectedImage!.lengthSync(),
        filename: selectedImage!.path.split("/").last));
    request.fields['userId'] = 'value';
    request.headers.addAll(headers);
    final response = await request.send();

    http.Response res = await http.Response.fromStream(response);
    print("reached");

    final resJson = jsonDecode(res.body);

    message = resJson['message'];
    print(message);
    setState(() {
      showSpinner = false;
    });
  }

  Future getImage() async {
    final pickedImage =
        await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    selectedImage = File(pickedImage!.path);
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ModalProgressHUD(
        inAsyncCall: showSpinner,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            selectedImage == null
                ? Text("please pick a image to upload")
                : Image.file(selectedImage!),
            TextButton.icon(
                style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                        Color.fromARGB(255, 62, 187, 0))),
                onPressed: uploadImage,
                icon: Icon(Icons.upload_file_rounded, color: Colors.black38),
                label: Text("Upload waste sample Image",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)))
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: getImage,
        child: Icon(Icons.add_a_photo),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```